# Good way to allow user to change city

Tags: forms, usability

I'm creating a site kind of similar to Yelp.com, so I was wondering what the best way to show users which city they are in:

1. The Yelp way: put two search boxes on the page, one for what your searching for and the other for which city to search for (You can also not just put in a city, but a neighborhood or zipcode). Yelp also displays a  "Yelp San Francisco" headline at the top of the container.
2. Put just one search box on the page ( I think it looks cleaner!) and display a headline in the container saying something like "San Francisco" with a small link saying "Change City" next to it.

Is there any other ways? Which is the best?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I'd do something like this:

[image: Yelp-like UX]

The reason behind, is that it's likely that your selection of cities at the first time will be limited. If it's not the case, then an open searchbox is better, but with a few cities the issue of cardinality kicks in.

Also, for two cities in a demo of my startup, I even used tabs:

[image: Nearby - my own little startup]

That's because it's only two cities. The most important question is, how many cities you have.

Comment: In my case, its national, so a lot of cities...Great answer!

Comment: Good answer, but your choice to use tabs in the examples is rather unconventional. Tabs are expected to have different content, the only difference between them shouldn't be just the name of the tab. In a case like yours, it makes more sense to have the city selection as part of the form rather than repeat the exact same form in different tabs.

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky: thank you very much :) like [this?](https://dl.getdropbox.com/u/7067930/nearby_main_form_wo_tabs.png) The main point is that this is an investors' demo page, we might support one more city, but it should shout from far away: hey! we support London and Budapest right now! - that's what the tabs were for visually. We even considered to have two separate subsites for the demo, but this is how it remained.

Comment: @Aadaam Yes, I think that's much better! The white on faint yellow is kind of hard to read, but in terms of layout I think it's much more appropriate than tabs.

Comment: very nice layout, Aadaam! A suggestion: I wouldn't use neither tabs nor the other way, as it seems that if you click on Budapest you could only search for locations in Budapest, I wouldn't like that as a user. Also, if you later adapt it or consider addresses slightly outside Budapest? But I thought you could make some small image slider (maybe to the left or to the right) with an image of the city and saying "Budapest, starting at €99" or whatever you'd like to... what do you think?

Comment: @user1553293: this is a great suggestion of Aadaam, to sort cities not alphabetically but by frequency, or if you don't have that data available, you could sort by inhabitants. There are even free data available out there (cities with lat, long, fibs region, inhabitants etc), so you could even calculate the nearest city easily...

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep it as one search field with some smart filtering. Maybe examples.

```
Search:
[                        ]
examples: "Hot Dogs" or "Beer, New York"
```

Comment: +1 - great answer, I'd have suggested the same. And the examples really help people to quickly understand they could search for both, location and search term! cool...